# Ubuntu 18 upgrade, should I allow it to upgrade to 20, what will be lost?

Tags: upgrade

My Ubuntu recently alerted me about upgrading to version 20.  I said OK and then when it had downloaded everything it said it would drop a whole bunch of things from my version 18.  I didn't really get what would actually be dropped.  I've added software I like and one that I like, Irfanview, is not available on my other computer that has version 20 on it.  So I wonder what other things will be lost.

[image]

Comment: As *yy* releases of Ubuntu use *snaps*, the applications you have added won't need upgrade, so the same *snaps* will operate in Ubuntu Core 18, as run in Ubuntu Core 20 post-upgrade. This is an advantage of *snap* based releases, but is it a *yy* release you're really asking about?

Comment: This question is too vague and too broad. We're not going to research and write a Term Paper for you detailing the hundreds of orphaned or other problematic packages that were routinely dropped from Ubuntu between 18.04 and 20.04. There is no `irfanview` deb package in any supported release of Ubuntu, old or new, though it is a Snap...so it wouldn't show up on such a list anyway. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1279697/edit) to be more specific and answerable, like "How can I install irfanview on 20.04?"

Comment: I wonder if you spelled it correctly.  I did and it is installed on my 18.04 computer right now.  I like it because it is easy to crop images.. . like if you take a screenshot, you can easily crop the window you want to send without sending the whole thing.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=irfanview   No Ubuntu package by that name for any supported release of Ubuntu (*yy.mm* releases anyway; *yy* releases use snaps so software doesn't change during upgrade, only the base system); if you believe it's spelled incorrectly you can provide the exact spelling in the package query.

Comment: I added the screenshot to the original post.